# 550 Junk mail rejected gmail @company .com

Tags: email, gmail, email-spam

Good afternoon.
I have the following issue
When I send from example@gmail.com to other gmails or company mails working properly.

But when I try from **example@gmail.com** to send to **example@company.com** I receive the following error

**550 "JunkMail rejected - mail-yb1-f181.google.com [209.85.219.181]:40242 is in an RBL: "**

If I send from another example_1@gmail.com   to   example@company.com working properly.

I check if the Ip is blacklisted but is not.

What I should try? Please help

Comment: Think you should ask Q like this at someplace like https://superuser.com/ rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you very much!Problem solved....a server for spam didnt update the list and blacklisted some mail.....server provider solved this by removing the email account from blacklist.